# Text displayed before the end of opening hours

Tags: javascript

This is a well working open-close script. What I would like to do is to have another text appear 15 minutes before closing time, saying that we are closing soon. Could you help me to complete the code?

```js
    var a = document.getElementById("telefon");
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
    var telefonweekdays = {
        0: null, //Sunday
        1: [8.30, 16.30],
        2: [8.30, 16.30],
        3: [8.30, 18.30],
        4: [8.30, 16.30],
        5: [8.30, 16.30],
        6: null //Saturday
    };
    var telefondayWorkingHours = telefonweekdays[n]; //Today working hours. if null we are close
    
    
    if (telefondayWorkingHours && (now > telefondayWorkingHours[0] && now < telefondayWorkingHours[1])) {
        a.innerHTML = "Most nyitva."; 
           a.style.backgroundColor = '#e2efd9'; 
           a.style.color = '#538135';
           a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
           a.style.padding = '0 4px';
           a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
           a.style.marginLeft ='5px';
      } 
      else {
         a.innerHTML = "Most zárva.";
           a.style.backgroundColor = '#efd9df'; 
           a.style.color = '#c91f41';
           a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
           a.style.padding = '0 4px';
           a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
           a.style.marginLeft ='5px';
    }
```

```html
<span id="telefon">

</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your values are hard coded you can check with `16.15` which is 15 minutes less than your closing time.

```js
    var a = document.getElementById("telefon");
   
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
    console.log(now)
    var telefonweekdays = {
        0: null, //Sunday
        1: [8.30, 16.30],
        2: [8.30, 16.30],
        3: [8.30, 18.30],
        4: [8.30, 16.30],
        5: [8.30, 16.30],
        6: null //Saturday
    };
    var telefondayWorkingHours = telefonweekdays[n]; //Today working hours. if null we are close


    if (telefondayWorkingHours && (now > telefondayWorkingHours[0] && now < telefondayWorkingHours[1])) {
            if (now == "16.15"){
          a.innerHTML == "Hamarosan bezár";
            alert("hello") // your logic for 15 mins before
        }
            
        a.innerHTML = "Most nyitva."; 
           a.style.backgroundColor = '#e2efd9'; 
           a.style.color = '#538135';
           a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
           a.style.padding = '0 4px';
           a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
           a.style.marginLeft ='5px';
      } 
      else {
         a.innerHTML = "Most zárva.";
           a.style.backgroundColor = '#efd9df'; 
           a.style.color = '#c91f41';
           a.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
           a.style.padding = '0 4px';
           a.style.borderRadius = '3px';
           a.style.marginLeft ='5px';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not very good. I want to send it to the website the same way as the others: a.innerHTML = "Now open."; How do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

let's say you like hard coded dates. you can create a function to check if the current time is during or beyond 15 minutes before closing time since your time outs have different times

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
var telefonweekdays = {
  0: null, //Sunday
  1: [8.3, 16.3],
  2: [8.3, 16.3],
  3: [8.3, 18.3],
  4: [8.3, 16.3],
  5: [8.3, 16.3],
  6: null, //Saturday
};

var telefondayWorkingHours = telefonweekdays[n];

if (telefondayWorkingHours && now > telefondayWorkingHours[0] && now < telefondayWorkingHours[1]) {
  // check if current time is during or beyond 15 minutes before closing time
  if (isFifteenMinBeforeOut(now, telefondayWorkingHours[1])) {
    console.log("we are closing soon");
  } else {
    console.log("we are still open");
  }
} else {
  console.log("we are close");
}

function isFifteenMinBeforeOut(current, clockout) {
  return current >= clockout - 0.15;
}
```

but I recommend you to try [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/docs/). there are lots of function you can use.

Comment: Before using moment, I'd strongly suggest the OP to use correct maths for the time, that is divide the minutes with 60, not 100! Your solution is great as it follows OP's code, and it works nice for 15 minutes before 16:30, but it wouldn't work for 15 minutes before 17, since 16.45 + 0.15 is not 17....

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work, nothing appears on the website. Could there be a bug?